PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 23): 2089
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
I hope that you're marking this special day with Friends. In honour of the occasion, please divide the following words into sets. Each set is associated to a thematic word, which you should identify. At the end you might find a message.












BALGOWNIE
BALKAN
BALTIC
BOMBO
CASH


CATARACT
CHLOE
CLINTON
CORDIALE
DILLON


DONG
GALE
KENT
MACARTHUR
MONTEZUMA


PAPI
POBBLE
QUAKE
QUANGLE-WANGLE
TREMOR


WAVE







HINT:

 The thematic words are structurally linked to the "special" day; none of them are the name of a person. If I were to give Trivial Pursuit colours to the thematic words, they might be* Green* Yellow* Blue (though with Pink in the set)* Blue (though with Yellow in the set)* Pink* Blue* Purple

HINT 2:

 Lousianian reassesses singing

HINT 3:

 Six of the words are surnames; two of the thematic words are very similar.

HINT 4:

 The surname GALE belongs to Dorothy

HINT 5:

 The surname KENT belongs to Clark


There are 21 words, so it's not the usual division into 4 categories of 4 words. Luckily, there aren't many ways to factorise 21, so here are the subsets of words:



 BALKAN, BALTIC, CORDIALE are all instances of an ENTENTE.




 DONG, POBBLE, QUANGLE-WANGLE are all from Edward Lear's NONSENSE poem. Thanks @Stiv for getting this!




 BALGOWNIE, BOMBO, CATARACT, are all suburbs of WOLLONGONG, Australia.




 QUAKE, TREMOR, WAVE can all be preceded by EARTH - so the word here (thanks @user39583) could be SEISMISM.




 CASH, CLINTON, MACARTHUR are all men from Arkansas, who apparently are called ARKANSANS. Thanks again @user39583 for finding the connection!




 CHLOE, MONTEZUMA, PAPI are all characters in a film - specifically, each of them is a CHIHUAHUA. Thanks again @user39583 - I would never have known about this!




 DILLON, GALE, KENT are all presumably KANSANS.



The OP says "At the end you might find a message." I think this means the thematic words should be

 put together and respaced,

or rather, more specifically (and following Hint 2),

 we're looking specifically for thematic words with repeated three-letter strings, and probably it's those three-letter strings that should be put together and respaced.

The letters are:

 NTE, NSE, ONG, ISM, ANS, HUA, ANS,

and (thanks @Stiv for spotting this)

 the final letters of these strings rearrange to MESSAGE, hence "At the end you might find a message"!


Nice work. I will say that you have correctly identified 3 sets and 1 thematic word.

Pretty sure you're going to want Pobble, Dong and Quangle-Wangle together... (google them as a set)

@DanielS With help from Stiv for one of the sets, I think I've now got all 7 sets and maybe 6(?) of the thematic words, as well as a potential route to the final expected answer.

@Randal'Thor Brilliant work! You have identified 4 sets (a couple more are lightly garbled), but have only one thematic word. I feel entitled to add a premature hint: rot13(Abar bs gur gurzngvp jbeqf ner gur anzr bs n crefba).

@Randal'Thor Sorry, on checking, you have 3 sets (you dropped one that you previously had)

@DanielS OK, now I'm confused. The only two sets I've dropped are CASH, CLINTON, MACARTHUR and BALGOWNIE, DILLON, POBBLE, but if either of those are right, it would mean that rot13(ONYTBJAVR, PNGNENPG, ZNPNEGUHE) is wrong, and I felt very sure about that one once I found it!

@Randal'Thor It is a very strong connection, but you might find other words with that connection (and tighten it further). Perhaps today's hint will help.

Given the rot13(pncvgnyvmngvba bs Sevraqf naq gur qngr) this puzzle has to be about rot13(SRFGVIHF) but I don't know how that helps

Given the new hint I suspect your first word is the one that's right... rot13(Vg unf n 3 yrggre ercrngrq fgevat RAG, yvxr gur bgure guerr jbeqf va gur uvag - Ybhvfvnavna unf VNA, rgp. Lbhe AFJ Jnyrf frg znl arrq 3 cynprf va Jbyy(BAT)(BAT) fcrpvsvpnyyl - 2 bs gurz ner ng gur zbzrag...) And if the word that links the Quangle Wangle category is 'nonsense' then that fits too...

Aha. Following the OP's hint, Dillon must be this guy since all 3 are fictional... Furthermore rot13(gur ynfg yrggref bs gurfr ercrngrq fhofgevatf fcryy ZRFFNTR, urapr svaqvat 'n zrffntr ng gur raq'!)
